# Is it necessary to write `firewall_name` when using `firewall_rule` resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I created a chef recipe for firewall.

```
firewall 'ufw'

firewall_rule "http" do
  port 80
  firewall_name 'ufw'
end

firewall_rule "https" do
  port 443
  firewall_name 'ufw'
end

firewall_rule "ssh" do
  port 22
  firewall_name 'ufw'
end
```

It works fine, but I feel it's bit redundant to write `firewall_name` in every resources.

Is there a way to set "default" firewall_name?

Comment: As stated below, you may omit it unless you start naming the firewall resource something other than `default`. It was simply a way to map all the rule resources to the firewall resource, without making the logic too complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, aside from the [default name which is `'default'`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/firewall/blob/master/libraries/resource_firewall_rule.rb#L12). I think it used to use the Poise helpers at some point but this was removed, otherwise I would say to make it a Poise subresource which handles this more intelligently.

Comment: Indeed, it used poise, but we had a lot of issues from folks who had conflicts between cookbooks that each used poise as a dependency, but were pinned to conflicting versions (e.g. `~> 2.0` and `~> 1.0`). Since we weren't using much of poise, it seemed easier to remove it at the time, then help folks reconcile different conflicting versions of poise from different dependencies.